# Style CustomWpfDataGrid in code?

Tags: wpf, styles, wpfdatagrid

I am trying to set the style in code but have been unable to do,

in xaml

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource DataGridControlTemplate1}"/>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="DataGridStyle2" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="AntiqueWhite"/>
</Style>
```

this is the CustomControl:

```
public class CustomDataGrids : DataGrid
{
    public CustomDataGrids()
    {
        ResourceDictionary res = Application.LoadComponent(new Uri("CustomDataGridStyle.xaml", UriKind.Relative)) as ResourceDictionary;
        this.Style = (Style)res["DataGridStyle1"];
        this.ColumnHeaderStyle = (Style)res["ColumnHeaderStyle1"];
    }
}
```

when Style=DataGridStyle2 it works perfect,but when Style=DataGridStyle1,it dosen't work,, any ideas?

Comment: Both templates are different. Better you set the background in DataGridStyle1 and then check.

Comment: Maybe the template with the key `DataGridControlTemplate1` has a problem. Could you post the code of that template?

Comment: Thank you for your attention,i understood that the problem is DataGridControlTemplate1,when i set template instead of style,it works perfect: `this.Template= (Style)res["DataGridControlTemplate1"];` ,but i don't understand why?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess The problem is the Template,so i had to do this:

```
This.Template=(System.Windows.Controls.ControlTemplate)res["DataGridControlTemplate1"];
```